# Стоит ли использовать нестатические методы для последующего создания объектов?

Tags: java, ооп

Есть необходимость сделать несколько классов для работы с массивами и числами, операции в основном наподобие "найти факториал" и "найти значение числа последовательности Фибоначчи".

Стоит ли для подобных задач создавать не статические методы, чтобы для вызова метода надо было создавать объект? В методах в основном используются математические операции для физических расчетов. Каждый метод возвращает определенное целочисленное значение как результат работы, которое применяется во вновь созданных классах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объект имеет смысл делать, если есть како-либо общее состояние, которое надо сохранять между вызовами.

В вашем случае нужно сделать простой утильный final-класс с приватным конструктором и статическими методами.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос немного философский. Но всеже же методы утилитных классов принято делать статическими. Как это сделано в Math, Collections, Arrays